# Rod bearing size

Tags: engine, mitsubishi, bearing, lancer

My son has a Mitsubishi lancer evo, MR 2.0 turbocharged engine, he spun a bearing. I used  plastigage and its reading .003, manual states standard rod bearing is .004 to.010 inch, with a limit of 0.02. I can't seem to find the exact thickness of the standard bearing, so what oversize bearing do I need? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Oversized bearing? You need far more than that. Unless you bought new rods and a crankshaft, you need to have machine work done to both to ensure they are right. If you don't, you'll be back in the same shape (probably worse) on first startup.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that, but when I was 20, I spun a rod bearing on my Rivera that had a 455  V8 engine and did the same thing , the only difference was my Dad was a machinist and he told me what size bearing I needed and I installed it and the car ran great and I never had another problem with that, and I didn't get rid of the car till 5 years later and it was still running strong, and at 20 with a 455 V8 I put it through a lot .

Comment: One other thing, the journal was barely scared, I've already sanded and polished it, it's not perfect but I got most of it out.

Comment: Just because it worked once, a long time ago, doesn't mean it was ok then or now.  You cannot just "sand and polish" a damaged crankshaft.  It needs to be precision ground and polished on a specialized machine that ensures it's perfectly round, parallel, and smooth.

Comment: I can see I'm not going to get an answer here just opinions. I'm looking to just get the car back up and running for my son, we don't have the money to have what your stating has to be done. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way, Mike. These aren't "opinions" we are telling you. It's the absolute truth. You can do as you please, but I'll give you about a 99.99% chance you'll either spin the rod bearing again within a short period of time and/or you'll have oil pressure issues, which will cause other issues. It's your money, time, and effort. Please do as you will.

Comment: Take the damaged crankshaft to an automotive machine shop.  They will be able to correct your damaged rod bearing journal by machining it to some spec that removes the damaged part.  Then they will tell you that you need an "X thousandths" oversize rod bearing.  If your rod big-end is not damaged you may be able to reuse the rod but it needs to be carefully inspected.  This is not opinion, as you seem to think, but just basic engine tech.

Comment: @jwh20 - It'd actually be an "undersized" bearing.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected.  It's likely not going to matter as it seems the OP is not interested in doing things properly.  In this case is doesn't matter at all.  Just put whatever you feel like in there and let the show begin.

Comment: I think in the OP's case, he should just put in something smaller than needed and let it self clearance. That should work out perfectly.